# Override Maven plugin configuration defined in the pom pluginManagement from the command line

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, maven-release-plugin

The POM that my project inherits contains some `<pluginManagement>` for the `release` plugin that specifies some additional `arguments`.

**My question is:** Is there a way to override the `arguments` parameter from the command line in this case?

The parent POM has this:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <arguments>-Prelease</arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```

Due to that the command line argument doesn't work:

```
mvn release:prepare -Darguments="-Pmock -Prelease"
```

The `-Darguments="-Pmock -Prelease"` part has no effect. When `arguments` is not already specified, it works.

It is not possible for me to modify the parent POM or not to use it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the solution. In *my* POM I add this which overrides the settings in the *parent* POM and allows to specify additional arguments on command line, e.g. `-Darguments=-Pmock`

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <arguments>${arguments} -Prelease</arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```

Answer (score 12):

You cannot override a configuration, which is already set in the POM (see [Maven Bug MNG-4979](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4979)). You may use variables in order to avoid this behaviour. The snippet of your answer makes use of it.

Comment: Updated link for MNG-4979: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4979