# How do I separate configuration for maven command line mojo invocation from global plugin configuration?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, cargo

I'm using the cargo plugin to deploy my app to a remote server during the build.  To do this, I have a configuration element for the cargo plugin.  Since there are two executions that use this single configuration, I use a global configuration element, i.e. it's not inside the executions.

I also want to execute a CLI invocation of the cargo:run mojo on this pom.  However, I don't want this execution to use the configuration at all.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override Maven plugin configuration defined in pluginManagement from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660047/override-maven-plugin-configuration-defined-in-pluginmanagement-from-the-command)

Comment: @DuncanJones I'm more specifically interested in how to use the xml configuration elements for both the command line invocation as well as the build execution.  I think that question is about -D params . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out maven [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). It's able to help you to deal with configuration divergence in different environments.

Comment: The profile mechanism somehow feels unclean to me, but it does work.