# Override Maven Plugin Version from Command Line?

Tags: maven, plugins, compilation, dependencies, overriding

How can I override a plugin's **version** in command line **without** changing pom.xml?

More specifically:

I cannot compile apache shiro commit 8dd6a13. The reason is buildnumber-maven-plugin version 1.0-beta-4 is not available any more. 
When I modify pom.xml and change the plugin version to 1.0, I can compile the project. 
I would like keep the project untouched, and just set the version of the plugin when I run mvn from command line.
I appreciate any insight and help.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Probably you are looking for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660047/override-maven-plugin-configuration-defined-in-the-pom-pluginmanagement-from-the

Comment: The version is available on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.codehaus.mojo%22%20AND%20a%3A%22buildnumber-maven-plugin%22), cause releases are immutable which means they will never be deleted. So there must be problem in your local setup.

Answer (score 5):

You can use maven properties to set default version, when you run from command line you will have possibility to overwrite it.

```
<properties>
    <buildnumber.version>1.0-beta-4</buildnumber.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${buildnumber.version}</version>

        ...

        <plugin>
    <plugins>
<build>
```

Now you can run, eg:

```
mvn clen install -Dbuildnumber.version=1.0
```

without settings property in command line maven will use default from pom.xml

Comment: That's certainly correct but the OP stated "**without** changing pom.xml".